# Pyodbc - “Server does not exist or access denied.”

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I already tried the solutions given here:
[Client-side pyodbc error: "Server does not exist or access denied."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31952368/client-side-pyodbc-error-server-does-not-exist-or-access-denied)

and i tried changing the driver to "{ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server}" which also did not work (yielded "Datasource not found" error)

So now im stuck here, and i hope someone has a suggestion.

I already verified the error is client-sided, as i was able to telnet the server.
This is my code:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('''Driver={SQL Server};
                        Server=tcp:localhost;
                        PORT=1433;
                        Database=Arduino;
                        UID=Python_Connect;
                        PWD=Python;''')

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dbo.Blackboard')

for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

This is the error i get (in german, but i think you get it...):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/formatting/converting/SQL Test.py", line 8, in <module>
    PWD=Python;''')
pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server existiert nicht oder Zugriff verweigert. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (10061); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Ungültiges Attribut für die Verbindungszeichenfolge (0)')
```

I listed the other available drivers and tried them, but i always get a "Connection denied" error then.

running `net start | "SQL Server"` yields this result:

```
C:\windows\system32>net start | find "SQL Server"
   SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
   SQL Server Browser
   SQL Server CEIP service (SQLEXPRESS)
   SQL Server Launchpad (SQLEXPRESS)
   SQL Server VSS Writer
```

Please go ahead and ask if you need additional information, thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the ODBC driver you try to connect using 32 or 64 bit platform? Are you using 32 or 64 bit Python? They need to match.

Comment: good idea, i dont know that, ill need to check that. you dont happen to know how i check what platform my odbc driver runs on? python is on 64bit

Comment: Run the ODBC Data Sources application. You find it by searching for "odbc".

Comment: when searching for "odbc" i get results for both 32 and 64 bit, kind of lost now :/

Comment: I think that is right. Check both and see where you find the driver you are trying to connect to.

Comment: i find the drivers i tried in both of them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204348/discussion-between-arghol-and-flying-thunder).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the results when you run `net start | find "SQL Server` from the Windows command prompt.

Comment: done, what is that telling me?

Answer (score 1):

In the end, my problem seemed to be that i used the syntax of `(Driver=foo;Server=foo;Port=foo)` which did NOT work! I had to use `Server=Server,Port`, and it worked!

Comment: Worth noting that specifying the port number is only necessary when trying to connect to a port other than 1433. That is the default port for a default instance of SQL Server, but named instances like \SQLEXPRESS usually **do not** listen on port 1433.